# How to check if there is a horizontal scroll with Behat?

Tags: behat

My case is as follows: sometimes on a stage environment one CSS file gets removed and that causes a horizontal scroll. My goal is to check if there is a horizontal scroll with a Behat script which will be executed on a cronjob and if that's the case - I'll send an e-mail. The thing is, that horizontal scroll is not a property. So my question is - how can I make Behat know, that there is a horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You must run your tests with a browser that actually renders the web page. Thus using the very fast `goutte` driver is not an option. Most likely you will have to use `selenium2` with Chrome or Firefox.

You must define an "appropriate" default screen size and start the browser accordingly.

Having done so you can check the `visible` property of `window.scrollbars` via Javascript. It is `true` if any scrollbar (horizontal or vertical) is currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `executeScript` with a javascript condition.

For example:

`document.documentElement.scrollWidth` will measure the width and

You can create a conditions that check for scroll and return `true` if present, else `false`.

For horizontal scroll:

```
executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollWidth>document.documentElement.clientWidth;");
```

For vertical scroll:

```
executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;");
```